# Ошибки js на других страницах html

Tags: javascript

Я часто испытываю ошибки, когда перехожу на страницу, где нет блоков, с которыми я работаю в JS, в то время как на нужной странице для которой и был написан код, он работает как и задумывалось.
Я понимаю, что надо обернуть код в какую-то проверку, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это должно выглядеть?
Например, на главной странице у одного из блоков есть сортировка по классу, которая работает и не выдает ошибок, но если перейти на другую html страницу, где нет этого блока, то я получу ошибку : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parentNode')". Для примера привел js код

```
const itemList = document.querySelectorAll('.products__item');
const wrapper = itemList[0].parentNode;
    document.querySelector('.choice__category-items').addEventListener('click', event => {
        if (event.target.tagName !== 'LI') return false;

        let filterClass = event.target.dataset['filter'];

      wrapper.innerHTML = '';

        itemList.forEach (elem => {
            if (elem.classList.contains(filterClass) || filterClass === 'all') {
                wrapper.appendChild(elem);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Ну вообще, достаточно обернуть все в условие с проверкой наличия на странице нужного блока., а если данный кусок кода предназначен только для одной страницы (одной группы страниц) , то можно вставить его непосредственно на эту страницу (в какой-то один шаблон).

Comment: @Zombotron можете написать, как выглядит данное условие?
раньше я использовал location.pathname, но что делать, если блок есть на нескольких страницах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно обернуть все в условие с проверкой наличия на странице нужного/ых блока/ов.
вот так:

```
if(
    (document.querySelectorAll('.products__item').length > 0)
 && (document.querySelectorAll('.choice__category-items').length > 0)
){ // просто проверяем или элементов с такими селекторами есть хотя бы по одному на странице, 
   // можно добавлять  && (document.querySelectorAll('...').length > 0) для любых селекторов

   // начало вашего кода
    const itemList = document.querySelectorAll('.products__item');
    const wrapper = itemList[0].parentNode;
    document.querySelector('.choice__category-items').addEventListener('click', event => {
        if (event.target.tagName !== 'LI') return false;

        let filterClass = event.target.dataset['filter'];

      wrapper.innerHTML = '';

        itemList.forEach (elem => {
            if (elem.classList.contains(filterClass) || filterClass === 'all') {
                wrapper.appendChild(elem);
            }
        });
    });
   // конец вашего кода
}
```